# How to SELECT a column composed by some other columns value

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a `daycode` column that stores values like 1,2...7
then in a different table I have cols like `field1,field2...field7`

I can join them on a `key`, but how do I select the specific `fieldX` column based on values passed?

```
Table 1 has the following columns
-------------
id
prodno
field1
field2
field3
field4
field5
field6
field7
```

Where each fieldX represents a value for monday, tuesday and so on till sunday.

```
Table 2 has the following columns
-------------
id
prodno
dt
daycode
```

**Update**

t2 has columns like field1, field2 ... field7, and daycode values is 1,2 ... 7. We need to concat "field" with the value taken from daycode column.

```
select table1.id,select [concat('field',table2.daycode)] from table1 join
table2 on table1.id=table2.key
```

Comment: I didn't understand the question!

Comment: Please provide the structure of both tables with sample data and expected output.

Comment: It would help if you wrote out the definitions of the two tables (possibly with values) and then showed what the join you want would return.  I believe he's looking for a result set like day1, field1 | day2, field 2 | etc...  If so, that's probably a pivot query.

Comment: This is symptomatic of a badly denormalized DB if the Foreign key in another table is determined by the value in a field in the primary table. I suggest you rework that data structure. It will only get harder as more code is written against it.

Comment: It is not, there is a correct foreign and primary key in both tables. I just want to get the record for a specific day. For each day there are 7 different columns. The primary key a product id.

Comment: ANytime you havea column with a comma delimted list, you are 90+% likely to havea database design problem. IF you are planning to use that column to join to other tables the probabilty goes up to 100%. You need to redesign to a normalized structure byt adding a table for that data. Nor should you ever have day1, day2, day3, day4, etc as fields. That too is a poor design structure and needs to be fixed with a related table.

Comment: How did you deducted that I have comma separated values? I don't have. I have 7 different columns for each day of the week. And one column for the day of the week to use.

Comment: Refer following link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21620860/how-to-get-column-value-which-define-in-another-table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create the statement in string an then execute it using `execute (@sql)`
or You can add a case statement in the select where You will pick the proper column.

Im not sure aobut this but you can try

```
SELECT t1.id, 
 CASE 
   WHEN daycode = 1 THEN t2.field1 
   WHEN daycode = 2 THEN t2.field2 
   WHEN daycode = 3 THEN t2.field3 
   WHEN daycode = 4 THEN t2.field4 
 END
FROM t1 join t2 on t1.id=t2.key;
```

Comment: +1, only way to do this is dynamic SQL.  @sql = 'select field'+table2.id'+'from...'     Dynamic SQL will introduce some security concern, give a web search to find out more

Comment: The best way though is to fix the bad design.

Comment: Can't change the table as it is the result of a sync process by some other service.