# How to get column value which define in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

Any one help me for following expected output? I have also added database structure

***TABLE1***

```
ID  Work Id Question                     Column  Column Type
1   1   What is your name?       field1   String
2   1   is you have mobile number?   field2   boolean
3   2   is you have passport?        field2   boolean
4   2   are you indian?              field4   boolean
5   2   abc?                         field5   Number
6   3   cde?                         field2   boolean
```

***TABLE2***

```
Id  WorkId  field1  field2  field3  field4  field5
1   1   JOHN      1         
2   2         1       0   1
3   3         0
```

***Expected Output***

```
Work Id Question                   Answer
1   What is your name?          JOHN
1   is you have mobile number?  1
2   is you have passport?           1
2   are you indian?                 0
2   abc?                            1
3   cde?                            0
```

***Table Structure***

```
CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/`testtest` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;

USE `testtest`;

/*Table structure for table `table1` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table1`;

CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `WorkId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Question` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ColumnRef` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ColumnType` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

/*Data for the table `table1` */

insert  into `table1`(`Id`,`WorkId`,`Question`,`ColumnRef`,`ColumnType`) values (1,1,'What is your name?','field1','String'),(2,1,'is you have mobile number?','field2','boolean'),(3,2,'is you have passport?','field2','boolean'),(4,2,'are you indian?','field4','boolean'),(5,2,'abc?','field5','Number'),(6,3,'CDE?','field2','boolean');

/*Table structure for table `table2` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table2`;

CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `workid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field1` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field4` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field5` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

/*Data for the table `table2` */

insert  into `table2`(`id`,`workid`,`field1`,`field2`,`field3`,`field4`,`field5`) values (1,1,'JOHN',1,NULL,NULL,NULL),(2,2,NULL,1,NULL,0,1),(3,3,NULL,1,NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

Comment: can you add your table structure ..

Comment: I have added table structure

Comment: How you will decide which field you are going to use as Answer

Comment: How you will decide which field you are going to use as Answer? because in first question you are using field1 as Answer and in second question you are using field2 as Answer and in 3 question you are using field4 as Answer and so on....

Comment: Relation between question and field is created by systemoperator (e.g. teacher) (dynamically set by project wise) , Answers will be entered by user (e.g. students)

Comment: how you are going to decide which field is refereed as Answers ?

Comment: table1 having question list and field name list, in table2 from field1 to field5 value means answers of that work questions

Comment: I know that  in table2 from field1 to field5 value means answers of that question but how will you decide which field is taken as final answere ?

Comment: these all are final answers ... If work1 having 2 questions in that if I have assign field1 to question no 1 then i can not assign field1 to question no 2...   similarly If work2 having 2 question in that also i have assigned field1 to question1 of work2 then i can not assign another question of work2......  work is differentiating.  Field values of In table2 all are final answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help you

```
SELECT t1.workid AS 'workid',t1.Question AS 'Question',
COALESCE(`field1`,`field2`,`field3`,`field4`,`field5`) AS 'Answer'
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.workid = t2.workid
```

*[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab2c48/13)*

Comment: Thanks Ashish, one issue occured in coalesce function does not evaluate to NULL value. I am trying to get count that How many times JOHN came, How many times true or false value came. some time user does not select option that time value stored as null so it means that Data is not available for that field, I want to show report of that "'माहिती उपलब्ध नाही'"

Comment: @NileshPatil I think the problem is in your table structure update your table structure. post new question for "I want to show report of that "'माहिती उपलब्ध नाही'" also read about How to replace null value in mysql.

Comment: Above query still not achieve required output